# Angular2 testing, SystemJS unable to load modules

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

My environment is setup very much like the official Angular2 quickstart with one difference: instead of `public/src/app`, I have `public/app`.

When trying to test a `Component` with a `ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild('profileModal')
profileModal: ModalComponent;
```

which is loaded in the component under test as:

```
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
```

`npm test` shows this error:

```
05 05 2017 17:45:48.218:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal
[1] Chrome 58.0.3029 (Mac OS X 10.12.2) ERROR
[1]   {
[1]     "originalErr": {
[1]       "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
[1]         "type": "microTask",
[1]         "state": "notScheduled",
[1]         "source": "Promise.then",
[1]         "zone": "<root>",
[1]         "cancelFn": null,
[1]         "runCount": 0
[1]       }
[1]     },
[1]     "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
[1]       "type": "microTask",
[1]       "state": "notScheduled",
[1]       "source": "Promise.then",
[1]       "zone": "<root>",
[1]       "cancelFn": null,
[1]       "runCount": 0
[1]     }
[1]   }
```

**karma.config.js:** [Elided for brevity]

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = appBase;      // app source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '.',

    proxies: {
      '/base/node_modules/': '/base/node_modules/'
    },
  })
}
```

How can I tell `karma` to load from `/base/npm_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal` instead of `/base/ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal`, as it is trying.

Using `SystemJs` instead of `Webpack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put it in the files section of the karma.config file, like this:

```
files: [ 'node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal.js' ]
```

Not sure if you already have that section in your config file, but just in case, keep in mind that you can pass your systemjs configuration to let it load your app and its dependencies:

```
files: [
    // System.js for module loading
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

    // Load any lib not included in systemjs.config here, like zone.js 
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',

    // RxJs
    { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
    { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},
    // Paths loaded via module imports:
    // Angular itself
    { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
    { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

    { pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
    { pattern: 'systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false },
    'karma-test-shim.js',
]
```

You can refer to this [post](https://psamsotha.github.io/angular/2016/12/16/angular2-testing-karma-systemjs.html) for more details about it.